# getting started to develop entire chess application

Tags: stockfish

Hi i love playing chess and i am software engineer.I want to create a chess web application for the sake of learning , so i need one chess engine,UI and one protocol as far as my knowledge.
For chess engine i have chosen Stockfish, but i am not sure for UI and protocol.The below are my questions
1.Already we are having quite protocols like ws(websocket) or XMPP why can't we use them as protocol?
2.For UI why can't we use simple html to design the page and we will use the images for corresponding pieces?
If this question is wrong in this forum please spare me.
Provide me any resources related to this topic 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to write a chess application such as playing against a chess engine, you'll definitely need to learn the UCI protocol. You won't go anywhere unless you master it. Stockfish, Houdini, Komodo and a dozen of other chess engines use it. Please google "UCI chess protocol" for more details.

1. This is probably out of scope. Anyway, there is no reason why you can't use an XML format. You might want to look up ajax, because this is how most of the web sites use to create an asynchronous behaviour.
2. It's not a good idea to use a simple HTML page, because you'll force the user to reload the entire page everytime you want to update the board. You'll need something asynchronous, such as an ajax call.

Please check and talk with lichess. They have a chat channel that you can use to talk with the programmers. Those guys know everything.